# Iterating over NEST Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying NEST out and it seems very nice, but I am having some trouble understanding some things.
The response is serialized to an hierarchy of objects. I would like to iterate over it and to create my own structure.
I would be able to do somethings like this (thanks to @Martijn Laarman, who helped me in the GitHub page):

```
var buckets = result.Aggs.Terms("level_1");
var term = buckets.Items[0].Terms("level_2");
```

It works, but I would like to have a generic algorithm that parses the response. To do that, I would like to get content independently of the query (if it used terms, range, etc). So I would like to do things like:

```
var buckets = result.Aggregrations["level_1"];
var term = buckets.Items[0].Aggreggation["level_2"];
```

Unfortunately the Aggregations collection returns Nest.Bucket and I can't do anything from there.
Is there any way that I can iterate over the result independently on how the query was formed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I was not able to find any way to do so.
I created a parser using a mix of JObects and Dictionary and operated over the JSON response to generate the output I wanted.

Comment: You might also be able to create an extension method on the Aggregations object in the response to re-compose it how you want.

Comment: The problem is that the Aggregations object doesn't provide an enumerator with which I can work on. Aggregations returns NEST.Bucket, but I can't get the items in this bucket :(

Comment: Oscar can you create an issue on github for this? It might require some thought how to expose a way to do this but might be very beneficial if its possible.